# Parallel LC circuit Q factor inductance role

Tags: resonance, theory

I'm wondering why Q factor in parallel LCR circuit is proportional of C and inversely proportional to L according to the formula \$Q = R \sqrt{C/L}\$ completely lost here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *I'm wondering why Q factor in parallel LCR circuit is proportional of
> C and inversely proportional to L*

As a slight help, if you considered a resistor in series with an inductor, the Q of that circuit is: -

$$Q_S = \dfrac{\omega L_S}{R_S}$$

But, you have \$L_P\$ and \$R_P\$ and, the \$Q\$ of the parallel combination is: -

$$Q_P = \dfrac{R_P}{\omega L_P}$$

So, \$Q_P\$ is inversely proportional to inductance

For a parallel RC circuit, Q is: -

$$Q_P = R_P\cdot \omega C_P$$

So, \$Q_P\$ is proportional to capacitance.

Now I know it's more complication for an RLC but I didn't want to do half a sheet of math to prove it when you can get a feel for the answer by analysing the parts.

Comment: Thank you for answer, could you also explain where from R parallel came?

Comment: @dimethyl it came from the body of your question; that is what you asked about.